# Incron feature in cloudlinux

Tags: linux, cloud, incron

Is `incron` is supported in `cloudlinux` ? After some googling I found that inotify is supported in cloudlinux. I couldn't find anything regarding to incron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work.It is just inotify based software.